# Azure python bot can't find module 'bot' on deployment

Tags: python, azure, sdk, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have an azure bot downloaded from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python and trying to run the 03.welcome-user sample. It runs fine locally in bot emulator. While deploying to Azure, the deployment is successful. But when testing via webchat, it receives messages but doesn't reply anything and the bot webapp log shows below message.

```
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568613378Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568617978Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568622279Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568626479Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568632579Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568636879Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568652580Z   File "/tmp/8dab68b1f2ac996/app.py", line 22, in <module>
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568657280Z     from bots import WelcomeUserBot
2022-10-25T13:19:05.568661580Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bots'
2022-10-25T13:19:05.595151696Z [2022-10-25 13:19:05 +0000] [80] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 80)
2022-10-25T13:19:05.940128122Z [2022-10-25 13:19:05 +0000] [71] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-10-25T13:19:05.946982159Z [2022-10-25 13:19:05 +0000] [71] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
app1_0_68010cbc_middleware for site amarapp1 initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-10-25T13:19:07.900Z ERROR - Container amarapp1_0_68010cbc didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Basically from above error it shows, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bots' . But bots is a sub directory in main directory where app.py is present and the whole thing was zipped together.

Any idea why its unable to find the bots package?

I have tried changing to relative path and provide explicit package.module name but nothing helped.

### Update 26-10-2022

There were some changes I had done to code for above error. So just to keep it clean, I deleted everything fresh downloaded from git and deployed the 03 folder bot to azure. Please see the error in webapp with clean code.

```
2022-10-26T10:49:22.579916760Z: [ERROR]    File "/tmp/8dab73b8cad6e69/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/integration/aiohttp_channel_service_exception_middleware.py", line 20, in aiohttp_error_middleware
2022-10-26T10:49:22.579934560Z: [ERROR]      response = await handler(request)
2022-10-26T10:49:22.579949661Z: [ERROR]    File "/tmp/8dab73b8cad6e69/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py", line 927, in _handle
2022-10-26T10:49:22.579953661Z: [ERROR]      raise self._http_exception
2022-10-26T10:49:22.579957161Z: [ERROR]  aiohttp.web_exceptions.HTTPNotFound: Not Found
...
...
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580275473Z: [ERROR]      self._creds.signed_session(session)
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580279473Z: [ERROR]    File "/tmp/8dab73b8cad6e69/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/app_credentials.py", line 98, in signed_session
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580283773Z: [ERROR]      auth_token = self.get_access_token()
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580287873Z: [ERROR]    File "/tmp/8dab73b8cad6e69/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py", line 65, in get_access_token
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580292173Z: [ERROR]      return auth_token["access_token"]
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580296274Z: [ERROR]  KeyError: 'access_token'
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580300274Z: [ERROR]
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580304274Z: [ERROR]   [on_turn_error]: 'access_token'
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580311174Z: [ERROR]  Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
2022-10-26T10:49:22.580396977Z: [ERROR]      return await inner_dc.begin_dialog(self.initial_dialog_id, options)
2022-10-26T10:49:22.560400947Z: [ERROR]  [2022-10-26 10:49:22 +0000] [69] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-10-26T10:49:22.567602910Z: [ERROR]  [2022-10-26 10:49:22 +0000] [69] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (69)
2022-10-26T10:49:22.568098728Z: [ERROR]  [2022-10-26 10:49:22 +0000] [69] [INFO] Using worker: aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker
2022-10-26T10:49:22.630360703Z: [ERROR]  [2022-10-26 10:49:22 +0000] [80] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 80
2022-10-26T10:49:32.289750856Z: [INFO]  11 added, 0 removed; done.
2022-10-26T10:49:32.289790758Z: [INFO]  Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
2022-10-26T10:49:32.317360563Z: [INFO]  done.
2022-10-26T10:49:32.338201623Z: [INFO]  Updated CA certificates
2022-10-26T10:49:36.186145580Z: [INFO]  warn: Middleware[0]
2022-10-26T10:49:36.186192282Z: [INFO]        At least one of http20OnlyDestinationHostUrl and http20OnlyListenUrl not provided
```

With clean code it is not able to find aiohttp which is why earlier I had changed the requirement file.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the sample?

Comment: Yes I did, I updated the requirements file include some specific packages as otherwise it was saying aiohttp not found etc. Please see question above, I added more details of error after testing again with no change to any code.

Comment: The process should be: Download sample, install `requirements.txt`, add required information in `config`, and then deploy. This is what you did, correct? Also, which version of Azure CLI did you use?

Comment: My Azure cli version is 2.41.0. And yes I downloaded sample, installed requirements.txt. Not sure what to do in "config". Can you please explain that part a bit? The bot runs fine in local.

Comment: You'll need Azure CLI 2.36.0 for Python. Your config file also needs to have the AppId and Password you created as part of the deployment process. See the [deployment docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Cjava) here.

Comment: If you're trying to build a **new** bot, please note that the Python and Java Bot Builder SDKs are being [retired](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python#:~:text=The%20Bot%20Framework,Virtual%20Agents.). You may want to use C#, Javascript, or Power Virtual Agents instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info about cli ver 2.36 and config files. I had seen it earlier but missed it since it's my first time.  Will try it. 

About Python and Java being retired, that's sad as I was trying python. People in my place are mostly using Power Virtual Agent. But PVA has very limited functionality which is why I wanted a custom bot with SDK. I do not want to use C# in SDK if that will retire also later. Lets say in 2-5 yrs, will SDK fully retire and PVA is the future?

Comment: There are currently no plans to retire C# or Javascript.

Comment: Thanks @AP01 for all the information!